# How to generate images in php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, image, drag-and-drop

Is there a way I can generate a single image out of several images dragged and dropped by the user at some positions of a div container?

I tried doing this using html5 canvas, however html5 canvas doesn't integrate using jquery to change the source of the images in a canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could post the image URLs and coordinates to a PHP script, and then (server-side) assemble the various images into one by using the PHP [image manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

**EDIT**

I'll give some short guidelines on how you can accomplish your task.

You will have a form with 3 arrays of hidden `<input>`s: image URLs, x coordinates and y coordinates of the placed images. They will be populated via jquery as the user [drops](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-drop) images into the container.

The assembling script would work in a similar manner:

1. Create a (big) empty container image (with [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)), let's call it `$imcont`
2. Read sequentially the POSTed URLs (e.g. `$_POST['url'][$i]`), open the corresponding image, and create an image for each one, with, e.g.,  [imagecreatefromstring](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)([file_get_contents](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)($_POST['url'][$i]));

   if you need the small image's dimensions, you can use [getimagesize()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) like this:

   `list($iwidth,$iheight) = getimagesize($_POST['url'][$i]);`
3. [imagecopy](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)() the image created at pt. 2 into `$imcont`, at the corresponding POSTed coordinates (e.g. `$_POST['xcoords'][$i],$_POST['ycoords'][$i]`)
4. Repeat pt. 2 and 3 for each posted image.
5. Save the generated image `$imcont`, e.g. if you want to create a jpeg image, use [imagejpeg](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)().

**Please note**

- To POST arrays from a form, use `[]` after the input name, e.g. `<input name="foo[]" ... >` ;
- `$i` is the index in the for loop;
- normally, you don't post the entire filesystem path,as required by file_get_contents(), so you'll likely have to prepend images' base directory to `$_POST['url'][$i]`;
- if you want to read images from an URL like `http://www.site.com/image.jpg` (opposite to a filesystem path like `/usr/share/images/image.jpeg`), you'll need [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled in your PHP  config;
- images will be copied into the container in the z-order of processing, i.e. the first one will be pasted below all the others.

Comment: Beautiful explanation, all that I needed for creating a app which the user drags stuff into his picture and then I generate a final picture with it.

Answer (score 1):

@Mohamed

If you want an example code maybe this will help you out a little bit
http://www.bolducpress.com/tutorials/how-to-make-custom-avatars-with-php/2/

Comment: Thanks Kemal, it's really a good one, put still can't figure out who to assign positions for each image instead of making all the images of the same size. Any Idea?